# How to print time elapsed (seconds) java

Tags: java, time, equation

in my run method of a game loop I tried to print the time the program has been running in java. I simply tried `System.out.println(System.nanoTime() / 1000000);` because that's how many milliseconds are in a second.(if you didn't know) It prints the seconds near the end but I wanted exact seconds for testing purposes. I searched online and someone suggested using the same formula I thought of. Can anyone give an exact one?

Comment: Why don't you just do `System.nanoTime() / 1000000`?

Comment: One thousand millis in a second yes. But it's called `nanoTime` for a reason...

Comment: @John Ah, I feel stupid I converted the wrong thing

Comment: @Mr.CodeIt a `nanosecond /1000000` is equal to one second (If you didn't know) haha simple mistake no big deal =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store previous time in a private member.

```
private long previousTime;
```

Initialize it in the constructor.

```
previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Compare it with current time in run method (each iteration of game loop)

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
double elapsedTime = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000.0;
System.out.println("Time in seconds : " + elapsedTime);
previousTime = currentTime;
```

Comment: That's itI needed help wit fps and stuff

Comment: That's what I had guessed (but did not go for aggressive assumption). Now that you have mentioned, it might be a good idea to print `1.0 / elapsedTime` (actual fps). It is easier to analyze and understand.

Comment: Also noticed that code in my answer was not compilable. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers provided, you could use a standard library [StopWatch](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html), like the one provided by Google's Guava API:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.start();
calculate();
stopwatch.stop(); // optional

long Seconds= stopwatch.elapsedMillis() / 1000000; // equals 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.currentTimeMillis](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) to get the current time in milliseconds.

If you pick this value at the start of your application and at the end, the subtraction of both values will give you the time your application was running.

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
// your code here...
final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println("The program was running: " + (end-start) + "ms.");
```

If you want it in seconds, just divide it with 1000 like you mentioned.

```
System.out.println("The program was running: " + ((double)(end-start)/1000.0d) + "ms.");
```