# How to display the build time in miliseconds? (JAVA)

Tags: java, time

Hi guys I made this code so far, but I need to display the execution time into miliseconds using System.currentTimeMillis(), but am not sure how!

```
public class Assignment4 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long value = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        int n=10;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           System.out.println(i);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print time elapsed (seconds) java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23207093/how-to-print-time-elapsed-seconds-java)

Comment: So, you want to display the difference between two points in time?

Comment: I essentially created a O(n) loop. I need to write down the execution time when N = 10 but the execution time right now just says 0 seconds, but I need that time in the miliseconds

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the timestamp at the end of the execution and subtract the initial one.

```
public class Assignment4 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long value = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int n = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.println(i);
        long totalTime =  System.currentTimeMillis()-value;
        System.out.println(totalTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the start and end time of the program, and print out their difference.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    int n=10;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       System.out.println(i);    
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end - start);
}
```